# Is it possible to charge photons

Tags: photons, visible-light, charge

For example there are anti-particles to every particle we know,

Similary in some sense, is there a possibility that we can charge photons..if not what are the reasons and has there been any attempt to do this experiment ? If it is possible to bend it than why not charge ?

Comment: Please reread what you have written. What is the connection of the existence of antiparticles with the question you are asking? At the particle level the verb "charge" has not definition. Particles have a charge (noun), a quantum number that characterizes them, which may be 0, +/-1/3, +/-2/3, +/-1 and some resonances +/-2.

Comment: @annav: I know there is no correlation..but the first question made me think of the other...they are not completely stranger !

Comment: Also, photons are their own antiparticle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At the particle level the *verb* "charge" has no definition. Charge cannot be added to a particle.

A particle *has* charge ( noun); it is  a quantum number that characterizes the particle, and its charge may be 0, +/-1/3, +/-2/3, +/-1 (and some resonances +/-2).

A photon has charge 0, spin 1 and mass 0.

[image]

That is why it is called a photon and not an electron.

> If it is possible to bend it than why not charge

That it can change direction ( bend) is a kinematic effect and controlled by the equations of motion. The quantum numbers are intrinsic and unchangeable in the definition of each particle.

Answer (score 4):

I think the closest thing to charged photons you are going to find, at least currently, are "gluons".  And you will be happy to know that they come with different combinations of *three* charges.  These particles are spin-1, massless, (just like the photon), and are charged.  They are responsible for the strong interaction in the standard model, and show up the most in the study of Quantum Chromodynamics (QCD).  For some more information see [Gluon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon) here for a brief overview.