# Is it possible to give photons an electric charge?

Tags: photons, quantum-electrodynamics, charge

I know that photons have no electric charge and that they are stable, but is it possible to give them a positive or negative charge? If so how?

Comment: The simple answer is no. The world would not have existed as we know it if photons had a charge. Look up "strong interactions QCD" where the gauge bosons are charged to see the difference.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31509/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Ok Qmechanic, so then would it be possible to guide, attract, or repel the photons using its electromagnetic force?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to charge photons](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38794/)

Answer (score 1):

charge is an intrinsic property of any particle. we  in principle cannot change the intrinsic property of any particle. photons are the carriers of electromagnetic interaction(action at a distance).